# How to show data in a Sharepoint gridview in sandboxed?

Tags: web-part

I am having a big trouble with showing data in a gridview.

All the guides on the internet is using LINQ, but i can not use that, because i create new Lists in Sharepoint, that therefore would not be in the entity class file.

I would be really glad if somebody could show how to get data from a list and show it in a webpart wihout LINQ:

I have this now:

```
        SPSite _sc = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb _w = _sc.OpenWeb();
        SPList l = _w.Lists["Navne"];
        SPListItemCollection lic = l.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem item in lic)
        {
            item.Title.ToString();
        }
```

I have searched to find the solution, but no answers.

Comment: all lists generate a webpart bound to this list. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: Because i will take multiple list and combine them into one.

Comment: Is there any common content type ancestor? if yes, this can be native. which edition of SP do you own ?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint Online, so that must be Foundation.

Comment: SharePoint Online uses SharePoint Server 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these 101 samples from Microsoft there is an example on how to use the Gridview.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-101-Code-da251182#content